# What is the meaning of the two different recording icons used in Windows 7 Media Center?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, recording, tv, tuner-card

I am using Windows 7 Media Center with a digital TV tuner. If I am watching live TV and then use the mouse to bring up the control buttons at the bottom of the screen and press the record button once, then a single red circle 'recording' icon appears at the left side of the time slider.  If I press the record button a second time, the 'recording' icon changes to a red circle with several shadowed circles fading off to the right.  Pressing the record button a third time halts the recording.

What is the meaning of the two different 'recording' icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is "record this movie/episode".

The second one is "record the whole series", e.g. repeats of a movie or other episodes of a TV series.